# Do RNNs such as LSTM only provide value for sequences where order matters?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I understand how LSTM can be useful for time-series or a series of words in order, but I'm curious if LSTM would provide benefit when the ordering of the inputs is not controlled.

For example, assume I'm trying to make a binary classification decision. My input is a list of 10 User IDs fed through an embedding, and that embedding sequence is fed into an LSTM and out into a single dense output node. If those user IDs can appear in any order, does using RNN/LSTM provide any value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oriol Vinyals has played around with this question. He wrote a paper about it here. https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06391

The short answer is that yes you can use LSTMs for sets that have no order but that you should still pay attention how you order the inputs.